# How to disable Battery running low message in ES File Explorer

Tags: es-file-explorer

I have installed ES File Explorer and I disabled almost all of its alerts.

When my battery charge is below 15%, an alert appears:

[image]

I can't find where to disable it, and when I press *View*, it shows the main launcher of my Android.

Do you have any idea how I could disable it?

Comment: This is because it can't figure out what it wants to be. Is it a File Explorer? Is it a Launcher? Or, is it a [Floor Wax](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wPO8PqHGWFU)? For certain, to me, it's over-engineered, and best ignored.

Comment: That once was a great app – until it became an ad platform. Plus even if I could ignore the ad part, I fully agree with @wbogacz: a file manager should be a file manager, and not a "we do everything a bit" (focus on one thing and do it real good is much better). **So:** Maybe time to switch to something else? I'd say *Amaze* looks like a good match – but it's free and open source, so no ads at all. Can be found at the [playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amaze.filemanager) as well as at [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.amaze.filemanager/).

Comment: @Izzy I really like that ES handles network seamlessly and I can share files easily on the network computers. I don't know what Amaze does but if it provides the same feature set, I'm willing to switch.

Comment: @Nestor You've got my full sympathy – those are reasons I loved ES for as well. And yes, I've named *Amaze* because it seems to cover the "useful parts" of ES quite well. Haven't fully tested it, as I rarely use a file manager on the device anymore. But: Nothing to lose, right? It comes at no cost and even made it to F-Droid, so it should be pretty safe privacy-wise as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to ES explorer app info and disable every notification from that app .

P.S : I used be a fan of ES before it became AD hungry , now i use Solid Explorer . I recommend it to you too .

Comment: I'll test Solid Explorer but it is a trial version. Should I buy the full version when it expires?

Comment: Yeah , it costed me just 20 INR ( less than 0.5$ ) . It is worth it